# How to UV a fence (or any other mesh) with repeating geometry?

Tags: uv, geometry

I have a fence that was generated from the [BagaPie](https://www.blendermarket.com/products/bagapie-assets) addon. However, it doesn't come with a useable UV. I plan on having many of these fences and other similar geometry like this in my scene, but I would really hate to manually UV all of it. I know I could make my own modular geometry with UVs and then try to stitch it all together, but generating geometry with BagaPie seems much faster, provided I could somehow automate UV generation.

What I want to do is to automatically unwrap everything, and then stack all similar UV islands together and resize the ones that are slightly off, so they all stack perfectly together, how can I go about doing that? I also have the [Zen UV addon](https://blendermarket.com/products/zen-uv), but I haven't gotten around to figuring that one out yet. Can anyone give me advice on that one.

[image]

Comment: Personally, this doesn’t look like a mesh that needs UV unwrapping. Procedural textures would probably be enough to make it look photorealistic.

Comment: I'm making assets for a game, so I don't think procedural textures would work for me

Comment: *Geometry Nodes* [UV Unwrap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.3/modeling/geometry_nodes/uv/uv_unwrap.html)?

Comment: Do you want the panels to be identical?

Answer (score 1):

*Note:* First enable the **Magic UV** add-on so that you have the copy/paste Uv's option in the UV's drop-down menu. **Preferences** > **Add-ons** > search for **Magic UV** and enable it.

Mark seams and UV unwrap one section of the fence, (large panel and its smaller supporting parts).

Next select this panel and its smaller parts > **UV** > **Copy/Paste UV** > **Copy** > **UVMap**.
[image]

Deselect All, then select all the other panels and their supporting parts >
**UV** > **Copy/Paste UV** > **Paste** > **UVMap**.
[image]

Now you should find that all the secondary panels and supporting parts will have had seams marked on them and their UV's stacked over the original panel's UV's as in the image below :
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's perfect and exactly what I wanted, I wasn't sure where to find the UV copy/paste function, since I didn't know about magic UV addon, but it worked, thanks.

Comment: Oooops! I am so use to having the Magic UV add-on I completely forgot that the Copy/Paste Uv's option wasn't part of the default Blender setup. I have edited my answer to include "First enable add-on ......."